# Prevent repeated starring and unstarring of messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, rate-limiting, abuse, chat-stars

It appears that you get to blink stars on any message as frequently as you want, as long as you want. Some child on The Bridge has just found out about this and the only approach I can think of - banning people at random until the abuse stops - is not something I feel like applying right now.

Please fix this, either through rate limiting, not counting unstar events towards your 30 star/day limit, shadow star bans or whatever means necessary and super-linear combination thereof.

Comment: Is it really that obnoxious?  You must really get mad at the drivers who leave their left blinker on.

Comment: @TheGrinch Yes.

Comment: @TheGrinch It also makes the list of starred messages on the right flicker each time the message is starred or unstarred, it's annoying in the way hyperactive animated ads are.

Comment: Alternatively, a mod/owner ability to see who's starred what would resolve the issue as well, and punish the user for the annoyance.

Comment: @TheGrinch you'd be surprised how annoying it can get after ~20+ minutes of it, since there's no detail on who is starring our moderators can't do anything about it

Comment: Does putting the room in timeout prevent starring?

Comment: @Shog9 Even if it did the timeout just gives this bored 7yo a countdown to precisely the moment where abuse may resume. We are [discussing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge) countermeasures but I can't think of anything given the current state of chat.

Comment: @Shog9 why would that be fair on all of the other people minding their own business and chatting?

Comment: @Flyk: It's not; I'm asking because badp reported having some trouble catching the star active. Honestly, this seems like a fairly minor form of griefing to me, but if it's bugging people then probably worth figuring out *some* way to mitigate it.

Comment: @Shog9 There is no big problem in stopping abuse on any one message; you can just delete it e.g.; this simply caused the child to target a different message.

Comment: @Shog9 probably the easiest way would be to make the act of unstarring not refund the star - that way the person in question has a finite amount of stars. Alternatively, implement something similar to the comment upvoting/un-upvoting where you prevent re-starring of a message. If you wanted to really push the boat out you could allow moderators to see who is taking part in this kind of behaviour so they could launch said user into the sun

Comment: Preventing re-starring probably wouldn't help. One could just star, unstar, and then move to the next message. That could stay annoying for a while.

Comment: @Flyk so you're saying that if they starred, unstarred, and re-starred, it would count as 2 stars?

Comment: @nhinkle correct

Comment: I think that's a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: Temporary visual fix for star area flashing: `(function(){var $s = $("#starred-posts"); var h = $s.height(); $s.css({height:h+"px",overflow:"auto"});})();`

Comment: Maybe it's morse code from users too low rep to comment

Comment: In my defence (although I doubt I'm the one @badp is referring to here), it's sometimes hard to hit the reply button when I'm on my iPad.  So I say [give us a proper tablet UI](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160597/can-we-get-a-better-chat-ui-for-tablets)!

Comment: @Flyk: As per my comment ^, that could punish tablet users who accidentally star in an attempt to reply.  As I often pull up chat on my iPad while, for instance, watching TV, I do not like the idea that I'll have fewer stars because I'm working with a somewhat broken UI.

Comment: Yeh, I really don't like the idea of preventing re-starring (or making it count against the star cap) ... not everything that's abused by a single user needs to be turned into an inconvenience for other people.

Comment: [My original question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142078) was just closed, so I'll bring it up here; this should include room owners removing stars.

Comment: Turns out [it's possible to see who starred a message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229913/180276), so there's something.

Comment: @badp, What does "child on  The Bridge" mean?

Comment: @Pacerier [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) chat room, i.e. [gaming.se]'s chat room.

Comment: I believe this has been implemented, right? @Shog9

Comment: Not exactly, NH. There's a time limit on retracting stars (as with votes on main), and moderators can put a stop to shenanigans on a specific message by clearing stars, but both of those have existed for many years.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion: Make it like a bit like close votes. You get one star action and one unstar action per message. The unstar should refund the star (because the way chat auto-scrolls makes it easy to mis-star), but you shouldn't get to re-star the same message once you've decided to unstar it.

Comment: Go through the backlog of thousands of messages for hours of starring fun.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Messages that are too old cannot be starred already.

Comment: I doubt that would solve the problem since the user could just as well go on a rampage and star 3 posts, then unstar them, then star 3 other (different) posts and unstar them, and so on...

Comment: @Shoe Put in a hard limit of unstar actions within a certain time frame then.

Answer (score 5):

Thankfully, one of those <strike>morons</strike> children has done it long enough so that I could take a video to better explain the problem. And as [you all can see](http://youtu.be/Cvekd2LzOuA), initially [with multiple stars](http://youtu.be/Cvekd2LzOuA?t=1m50s) to later [become redundant](http://youtu.be/Cvekd2LzOuA?t=3m32s),  this is quite annoying.

I'd suggest to block the user from starring (put a star on) any post for `x` hours after `n` (personal preference goes to the number 3) star/unstar actions within `t` hours.

Comment: A maximum of 3 stars every 1 hour sounds way too heavy handed. Applying, say, a 1 hour cooldown after 15 (un)star events in the same minute or so would effectively curb the abuse while allowing normal use of chat. If we only count events that change the message score between 1 and 0, the thresholds could be even lower. That said, this is probably an approach that would be kinda too hard to code in.

Comment: @badp, with `n` I mean star -> unstar (a click on the star and another click on it) actions. I use the chat a lot and that I recall I've only unstarred a message 3 or 4 times in the last year, I think 3 times in an hour is pretty light handed tbh.

Comment: @badp, as for coding, this gets as "simple" as loggin every unstar actions and check if the amount of unstar actions is `> n` within a `t` hours span period in the last `x` hours.