# Why can't we have more stars in chat?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, chat-stars

I don't see the purpose of the star-limit. Why is there one? And, if possible, can we have unlimited stars? [We do after all, have some star-happy users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22148910#22148910).

Comment: We all know that user is you, Ethan.

Comment: Your link doesn't really support your case. (in fact, quite the opposite)

Comment: Maybe I am cynical, but this looks like a request for an easy way to get the silver Outspoken badge - I would say the star limit is sufficient.

Comment: @santiago Getting that badge isn't too difficult in [the 2nd monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor). I have no idea what the results would be for other chat rooms.

Comment: Very difficult in just about all the chat rooms I frequent

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stars are designed, like upvotes and close votes, in that, they should be used sparingly to determine the worth of questions, or in this case, chat posts.

Whilst in [The 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor), starwalls and [pointless starring](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1629/62429) are somewhat commonplace, other chat rooms [don't take so kindly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22139771#22139771) to over starring things.

By limiting stars you can avoid situations [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIJkm.png).

With unlimited stars, you could potentially star everything and then the whole idea of starring to highlight interesting content would become pointless.

Comment: Unlimited stars would also be even more [obnoxious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209950/180276), exacerbating the problem of the already-infuriating "star troll." +1