# Sensitive flagger data is exposed via chat WebSockets (and possibly /events), allowing "private" flags to be publicly visible

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, privacy, chat-flags

So, after [I figured out that I could see who starred a message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229913/180276) (highly related), I figured I might be able to find out the flagger of a message too. So I tried. Here's some data from my logs:

```
hichris is about to flag

{"event_type"=>1, "time_stamp"=>1398388054, "content"=>"Flag now?", "id"=>28079239, "user_id"=>10308
1, "user_name"=>"hichris123", "room_id"=>11540, "room_name"=>"Charcoal HQ", "message_id"=>15148938}
{"event_type"=>1, "time_stamp"=>1398388055, "content"=>"k", "id"=>28079240, "user_id"=>103081, "user
_name"=>"hichris123", "room_id"=>11540, "room_name"=>"Charcoal HQ", "message_id"=>15148939}

Here's where hichris flags.

{"event_type"=>9, "time_stamp"=>1398387950, "content"=>"@Doorknob This is <i>so</i> offensive.", "id
"=>28079242, "user_id"=>103081, "user_name"=>"hichris123", "room_id"=>11540, "room_name"=>"Charcoal
HQ", "message_id"=>15148916, "parent_id"=>15148878, "message_edits"=>1, "message_flags"=>1, "show_pa
rent"=>true}

Now he reports the fact that he flagged...

{"event_type"=>1, "time_stamp"=>1398388067, "content"=>"There.", "id"=>28079244, "user_id"=>103081,
"user_name"=>"hichris123", "room_id"=>11540, "room_name"=>"Charcoal HQ", "message_id"=>15148941}

Now I handle that flag as invalid:

{"event_type"=>9, "time_stamp"=>1398387950, "content"=>"@Doorknob This is <i>so</i> offensive.", "id
"=>28079245, "user_id"=>59776, "user_name"=>"Doorknob", "room_id"=>11540, "room_name"=>"Charcoal HQ"
, "message_id"=>15148916, "parent_id"=>15148878, "message_edits"=>1, "message_flags"=>1, "show_paren
t"=>true}

And I thank hichris

{"event_type"=>1, "time_stamp"=>1398388074, "content"=>"Thanks!", "id"=>28079247, "user_id"=>59776,
"user_name"=>"Doorknob", "room_id"=>11540, "room_name"=>"Charcoal HQ", "message_id"=>15148943}
{"event_type"=>1, "time_stamp"=>1398388077, "content"=>"(marked as invalid :P)", "id"=>28079248, "us
er_id"=>59776, "user_name"=>"Doorknob", "room_id"=>11540, "room_name"=>"Charcoal HQ", "message_id"=>
15148944}

Now I am examining my logs, which is the stuff you're looking at now

{"event_type"=>1, "time_stamp"=>1398388080, "content"=>"Examining logs", "id"=>28079250, "user_id"=>
59776, "user_name"=>"Doorknob", "room_id"=>11540, "room_name"=>"Charcoal HQ", "message_id"=>15148946
}
```

And then:

```
PearsonArtPhoto arrives and flags as invalid (setting message_flags to 0, since he's a mod).
It's *highly* troubling that I can figure this out.

{"event_type"=>9, "time_stamp"=>1398387950, "content"=>"@Doorknob This is <i>so</i> offensive.", "id
"=>28079251, "user_id"=>3087, "user_name"=>"PearsonArtPhoto", "room_id"=>11540, "room_name"=>"Charco
al HQ", "message_id"=>15148916, "parent_id"=>15148878, "message_edits"=>1, "show_parent"=>true}
```

The implications of this is that **anyone** with 10k rep can see supposedly "private" flagging information. **Anyone** can see **who flagged a message**, **who flagged as valid**, and **who flagged as invalid**. This is a **major** problem.

I'm fairly sure that the WebSockets work the same way that `/events` does. I still haven't figured out the right timestamp to send, but if I'm right, this means that **anyone can see *all* flags *ever* made**.

(This is a separate post from the "seeing stars" post because 1. it's about a different mechanic, 2. it's *much* more urgently in need of fixing, as it exposes potentially privacy-violating data, and 3. it may be fixed in a different way (hopefully sooner).)

[Here is the conversation about this in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/conversation/on-seeing-the-users-that-flag-messages)

Can this be fixed, preferrably as quickly as possible?

Comment: *This is even worse than heartbleed!!!* :P (+1, nice find)

Comment: There's no flag 'requires developer attention' :)

Comment: So ... you mean I can't deny my chat flags ... dangit, this NEEDS to be fixed now!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apologies for the delay in answering: sometimes things slip through cracks; triage is not perfect.

The behaviour is unfortunate, and I will endeavour to investigate and remedy this.

Note: an initial glance suggests that "flag for moderator attention" flags are not impacted by this. Only spam/offensive. Likewise, it is not correct that all flags "ever" are recoverable: the window of data available via the scrolling event loop is pretty small (beyond that the client application simply requests a full page reload).

I will, however, investigate how this can be addressed.

Update: this change is deploying now; for these events, the user-id (used to change the UI experience) is now only included for your **own** events. For other events this is omitted.

Comment: False. Confirmed that I can still see flagger identity on my own posts, and on other people's posts. We did that experiment yesterday (as well as with stars).

Comment: @SecondRikudo that's odd; will double check

Comment: This still appears to be able to be exploited.

Comment: Marc, any update on this? It's been exploited a couple times before, and because of this behavior a "script" can be run to see who flags stuff.

Comment: @hichris I will investigate in the morning (late evening here)

Comment: Did you find anything that may have caused this still to be exploited?

Comment: @hichris123 deploying something now; it is hopefully resolved