# Why was one Informed badge awarded here on Meta?

Tags: bug, badges, meta, informed-badge

I've gathered from [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188544/informed-badge-for-meta-stack-overflow) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231035/informed-badge-on-meta) that the Informed badge is not awarded here on the Big Meta.  But [one user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/269845/petseral) does have this badge.  Why did this one user get the badge when the rest of us can't?

Comment: Make it two. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ... how...?

Comment: Heh, maybe they just don't send the 'read tour' request from the client, but the server will still accept it.

Comment: @hichris123 cheating. I'm still trying to figure if it's considered hacking and better be sent in private to the team, or being one bronze badge be made public. Oh, Jeffrey nailed it, leaving it to you to figure the exact request. :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's one bronze badge, so I don't think it's *that* important. But I'll pass this on to the dev team for you.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Sorry, once someone demonstrated it on demand it became obvious what's happening.

Comment: Hmm, now there's three! How odd...

Comment: @Doorknob lol! Sent an email, wonder if they'll bother to block it, or let those who got into so much trouble to keep their badge. :-)

Comment: I'm more surprised that we're *not* awarding this badge on MSE, to be honest.

Comment: There are [four users with the Informed badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/194/informed).

Comment: @Anna who forgot to raise the flag? ;)

Comment: @AnnaLear A byproduct of the pseudo-parent site http://stackexchange.com/ having a badge-less tour page?

Comment: @CareBear Nah, that's a completely different codebase.

Comment: We should just keep it but rename it to, say, "Source Diver" here on meta. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear - this raises the question: are there any other API loose ends not verified by the server?

Comment: @DeerHunter This is more of a config mismatch than an unverified route. The badge *should* be disabled and therefore not awarded to anyone hitting the route, but for some reason it's not. I haven't had a chance to properly dig into it yet.

Comment: @DeerHunter: There [have](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215229/i-can-dispute-flags-without-10k-rep-and-so-can-you) been [some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225182/did-you-know-that-10k-users-can-see-deleted-comments) in the [past](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230435/sensitive-flagger-data-is-exposed-via-chat-websockets). [Some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160338/allow-moderators-to-reply-to-a-flag/220276#220276) were [even](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it/216147#216147) later made official.

Comment: @DeerHunter: And, of course, [here's maybe the most famous one](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Good idea, and the description should say: "awarded for figuring out how to get this badge". This is Meta, after all.

Comment: @Anna should we change the question here to be a feature request "Please grant the informed badge here on MSE"? Any point in this?

Comment: @shadow Nah, no need.

Comment: @Anna OK, but I will keep asking from time to time about it. ;-)

Comment: @Shadow Yeah, sorry, I completely forgot about this. Thanks for the reminder. :)

Comment: Looks like 14 people have the badge now. I didn't get it (yet) after going through the tour. So is this still only for people who cheated? ;)

Comment: @RetoKoradi  The standards for being *Informed* are higher on this site. Scrolling a page doesn't cut it here; one has to be also informed of the code behind the page.