# Stack Exchange "tour" page does not show I'm logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stackexchange.com, tour

As you can see in the screenshot, I am logged in https://stackexchange.com/ itself:

> [image]

However, when clicking "Learn more" to reach the [tour page](https://stackexchange.com/tour), I am no longer logged in:

> [image]

Clicking "log in" takes me through all the steps to create account on a new Stack Exchange site, eventually putting me back in the tour page, in the same state exactly.

The weird part is that the "Your Communities" list is OK and showing my own communities, so looks like it's a bug in the top bar somehow.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen an earlier bug report by a low rep user that was closed (and as I can't find it anymore probably deleted by now) because it complained about not getting the informed badge which is due to this bug... voting to close to a non-existing question...

Comment: @rene sure you're not being confused with [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240728/why-was-one-informed-badge-awarded-here-on-meta)? Stack Exchange portal isn't a Stack Exchange site, so no badges there.

Comment: that is the one... and yes, I'm confused as always, you better get used to that....

Comment: @rene lol, getting used bit by bit. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug was actually in /tour itself. Turns out we were inheriting from the wrong controller class there.

Fix coming in the next build. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Last (promise! ;)) can you enable the Konami code there like all other Tour pages? Pretty please? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Maybe later. :) I have some actual work to do first.

Comment: lol, fair enough. */crawls back under the blanket*