# Can we have a title for stackexchange.com/tour?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tour

Can we please have a title such as 'Stack Exchange Tour' on https://stackexchange.com/tour?

It doesn't look very nice to just have the address as the title...

from this:

[image]

to this:?

[image]

Comment: IMHO it's a [tag:bug], but you've got Anna Lear seeing it, so it should be resolved quickly I think ;)

Comment: @Anna thanks, blonde moment on my side, forgot the [tag:title] tag is only for question titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well spotted!

A fix is rolling out right now:

[image]

Comment: I like your tab colours matching the SE topbar colours :)

Comment: Almost black is all the rage. ;)

Comment: @ṧнʊß And now I know that finding the name of your current Chrome theme is surprisingly difficult. But, here it is: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blue-space-sunset-chrome/nndfdjfoclbidmgpmbelcieibgjjfdog?hl=en

Comment: While you're there, any chance to fix [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242304/stack-exchange-tour-page-does-not-show-im-logged-in) as well? :)