# Is it possible to filter the star list in a room for a specific user?

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars, chat-search

As the title says, I am wondering if there is a way to filter the list of starred messages in a room to only show the message that were starred by a specific user.

Showing the message that were starred by "me" is easy

> ?tab=stars&filter=**mystars**

But does an equivalent filter that allows filtering for a arbitrary user exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not exist because [who starred a message is *private* information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264580/295232). Not even room owners and moderators can see who starred a message (which leads to [other problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297793/295232), but I digress ...)

Comment: bingo. You are right - why I didn't think of that. I guess it is better to NOT post question when you have a cold ^_^'.